# Mock azure create file - delete file on blob storage using nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to mock the creation/deletion of a file on blob storage and I don't know how to do it
I did this as :

```
//create file
  const blobService = azure.createBlobService(storageAccountName, accessKey);
  await workbook.stream.pipe(
      blobService.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(containerName, blobName)
  );
```

//Delelete file :

```
 blobService.deleteBlobIfExists(containerName, fileName, (err: any, result: any) => {
    if (err) { reject(err);
    } else { resolve({statusCode: 200});}
});
```

I did that to get connection information:

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';
BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('fromConnectionString-test');
console.log(BlobServiceClient.prototype.getAccountInfo());
```

I've some error that logic because i'm not sur the connection is correctly mocked...

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAccountInfo' of undefined
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the account info from the prototype. However, instead of that, you will need to instantiate `BlobServiceClient`:

```
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
  AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
);
StorageAccountInfo accountInfo = blobServiceClient.getAccountInfo();
```

See

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs?tabs=environment-variable-windows
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient.getaccountinfo?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-storage-blob-blobserviceclient-getaccountinfo()

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but this does not simulate the creation or deletion of files on azure blob storage in unit test. (i'm new on unit test using JEST) I don't know I was clear

Comment: @Motra you will need to mock `blobServiceClient.getAccountInfo` in order to test this with Jest. But independently of that, this function is an instance method and you need to call it as such.

Comment: Thanks @Lajos for your return.
In fact xwxx it was just to know if I established the connection in mocking mode. If my goal is to be able to mock the main methods like [deleteBlobIfExists, download, createWriteStreamToBlockBlob, ...], but I have no idea how to go about it. I don't know if it's clear now